# Creating loops to read an ascii (.txt) file by piping it into a program and then outputting it into another file

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, ascii

I am trying to essentially pipe a .txt ascii file into a program. My program needs to be able read the lines upon lines of ascii code and then output what it reads into a file. At which point i will compare the file I just filled with ascii to another file which has the correct output of the file already using the diff command. I am really new to C (it's my third week, with once a week lab instruction time with my prof), and I feel I'm quite close to figuring this out, but i feel the nesting of my loops is off.

The three files I'm dealing with:
    encoded_picture.txt
    decoded_picture.txt
    ascii_cat.txt

eg (encoded_picture.txt) Using `less`

29: 1. 1  4. 36: 1. 1  4. 3  2. 1: 1. 5  1. 1: 1. 8: -1?
30: 2. 39: 1. 1  3. 3  4. 7  1. 6: 2. 1: -1?
12: 1. 58: 6. 2  2. 9  1. 6: 2. 1: -1?
12: 2. 57: 1. 1  3. 1  3. 11  1. 8: -1?
12: 3  1. 55: 2. 2  1. 1  2. 12  1. 8: -1?
12: 1. 3  1. 53: 1. 1  1. 1  4. 13  1. 8: -1?
12: 1. 5  51: 8. 15  8: -1?
13: 1. 1  2. 2  1. 49: 7. 5  2. 9  8: -1?
14: 2  2. 2  1. 48: 6. 6  3. 2  1. 5  8: -1?
14: 1. 2  2. 3  1. 45: 6. 8  3. 1  2. 4  8: -1?
15: 1. 1  3. 3  1. 44: 5. 7  2. 1  6. 2  1. 8: -1?
16: 1  4. 4  1. 41: 5. 5  6. 1  5. 2  1. 8: -1?
16: 6. 5  1. 38: 6. 3  8. 1  5. 2  1. 8: -1?
17: 6. 5  2. 35: 6. 3  9. 1  5. 2  1. 8: -1?
17: 7. 6  2. 32: 6. 5  8. 1  5. 2  1. 8: -1?
18: 7. 7  1. 30: 6. 5  7. 1: 1. 1  3. 1  1. 2  1. 8: -1?

eg. (decoded_picture.txt)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::..  .....:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::..  .....    ...::..      ..::..:::::::::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::...::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::..  ....    .....        ..:::::::...::
:::::::::::::..:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.......   ...          ..:::::::...::
:::::::::::::...::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::..  ....  ....            ..:::::::::
:::::::::::::    ..::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::...   ..  ...             ..:::::::::
:::::::::::::..    ..::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::..  ..  .....              ..:::::::::
:::::::::::::..      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.........                :::::::::
::::::::::::::..  ...   ..::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::........      ...          :::::::::
:::::::::::::::   ...   ..:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.......       ....   ..      :::::::::
:::::::::::::::..   ...    ..::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.......         ....  ...     :::::::::
::::::::::::::::..  ....    ..:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::......        ...  .......   ..:::::::::
:::::::::::::::::  .....     ..::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::......      .......  ......   ..:::::::::
:::::::::::::::::.......      ..:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.......    .........  ......   ..:::::::::
::::::::::::::::::.......      ...::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.......    ..........  ......   ..:::::::::
::::::::::::::::::........       ...:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.......      .........  ......   ..:::::::::
:::::::::::::::::::........        ..:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.......      ........::..  ....  ..   ..:::::::::
:::::::::::::::::::..........        ..::::::::::::oooo:::::::ooo:::ooo:::......      .........:::   ..  ..    ..:::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::.........         ...::::::oooooOO&&OOooooOOooOOOOOOOOoo::.....       ..........::..    ..    ..:::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::..::::..::.....        ...::::ooOO&&OOO&&&&OOOO&&&&&&&OOOOOooo::..       ...........::..       ..::..::..::::::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::..::....     ....::oooOO&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&OOOOooo::oo::        ....:::........       ..:::::..:::::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::...    ::::oooOO&&&&OO&&&&&&&&&&&&OOOOOoo::...         ...:::::::.....       ..:::::::..:::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::....::oooOOOO&&&&OO&&&&&&OO&&&&&OO&&OOOOooo::::..      ........::::....       ..::::::::..::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::oooo::::::ooooOOOO&&&&OOOOO&&&&&OO&&&&OOO&&&OOOoooooo:::..  ....  .......:::...        ::..::::::..::..
:::::::::::::::::::::::ooo:::::::::oooOOOOOO&&&&OOOOO&&&&&OO&&&&OOOO&&OOOOOoooo:::..:::..       ....::...   ..    ..:::...:::::..::
:::::::::::::::::::::ooo::::::::ooooOOoooOOOO&&&&&OOOOO&&&&&&&OO&&OOooOOOOOOOOOooo::ooo.....        ...        ..::.....:::....
:::::::::::::::::::::ooo::::::oo::ooOOOOOOOO&&OO&&OOOOoooOO&&&&OO&&OOO&&OOooOOOOOOOOOooooo:::::...........        .....::.......
:::::::::::::::::::::oo::..::...::ooOOOOO&&&OO&&OO&&OO&&OOOOOOO&&&&OOOOOOOoooOOOOOOOOOOOoo::ooo::::...   .....       ..::...........
:::::::::::::::::::::::....::oooOO&&&&&&&&OO&&OOOOOOoooOOOOOooOOOOOOooooOOOOOOOOOOoooooo::.....     ..       ..::......:::....
::::::::::::::::::::::...:::ooOOOO&&&&&&OOOOOOOOOOoooOOOOOooooOOoooooooOOOOOOOOOOoooooo:::....       ..    ....::..::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::....::OOO&&&&&&&&OOOOOOOOOoooo&&OOOoooooooooooooooOOooooOOOOoooooo::....      ....  ...::....::::::::
:::::::::::::::::::::...  ..::oo&&&&&&&OOOOOooOOOoooooooOOOOooooooo:::oooooooooooOOOOooOOoooo:::::..         ..::::...::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::....::ooOO&&&&OOOOOOOooOOooooooooooOOoo::oo:::oo:::ooooooooooooOOoooOOoooooooo..         ..::::::..:::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::....::OOO&&&OOOOOOooOOoooo::ooooo::ooOOoooo:::::::::oooo::ooooooOOOOOOooooooo..         ..:::::...:::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::..  ...ooOOOOOOOoooooo::::oooo::..ooOOoooo::..:::::::::::oooooooOOOOOOOoooo::..         :::::::..:::::::
:::::::::::::::::::::::...::OOOOooooooooo:::..::ooo:::..::OOooo:::..:::::...:::::oooooooooOOooooooo::..        ..:::::::::::::..
:::::::::::::::::::::::::ooOOOoooooo:::ooo::...::oo::::..ooOOooo::....:::....::::::::ooooooooooooo:::..       ..::::::::.....:::
::::::::::::::::::::::::oooooooooo:::::....:::::...ooooo.....::::....::::..:::oooooooooooooo::..      ..::::::::::::oo:::
::::::::::::::::::::::::oooo:::ooooo::::.....:::::..::ooooOO::........  ...::...:::ooooooooooooo::..       ..::::::::ooo::oo::::
:::::::::::::::::::::::oooo:::::::::::..    :::::..::OO:::OO::........   .....:::::oooooooooooo::       ..::::::::oo::::::oo
::::::::::::::::::::::oooo::::::::::::..   ....::...OOoo:::OOoo..::....     .....:::::::::oooooooo::..      :::::::::oo::::::oo
:::::::::::::::::::ooooooo:::..::::::..::..........::OOoo:::OOO::.....     ......:::::::::::oooooo::..     :::..:::...::::::...::
:::::::::::oo::::::::oooooo::....::..::oo::   ..........ooOOooooOOO::  ...       .....:::::::..::::ooooooo::..    ..::..:::...::::::..  ..
::::::::::oooo::::::oooOOOOoo....:::..::oo..    :::......::OOOoooOO&&OO::            ....:::::.....::oooooooo::..    ...:::...:::::.....
::::::::ooooo:::::::ooOOOOoo::....:::..ooo..    ::&&oo.....::OOOooOO&&&OO::              ........  ...:::ooooooo::..   ....::...::..::::::..
::::::ooooooo::::::ooOOOOOoo::....::...:::..    ::&&oo.....::OO&&OO&&&&OO..         ..      ..oo::  ...    ..::::oooooo::......::...:::ooo::::..
::::::ooooo:::::::OOOOOOOoo::::..:::  ...    ..oo&&:::....::OO&&&&&OOoo..        ...      ..:::  ....    ..::::ooooo:::::...ooo::ooo:::.....
:::::ooooo:::::::ooOOOOOOOoo:::::::.....   ::&&OO..::..  ..::OO&&&&OOoo::..       ....      ..::...........:::ooooooo::oo:::ooo:::........
::::ooooo:::::::ooOOOOOOOOOoo:::..:::..   ....::oo.......OO&&&&&OOoo::..       ..::..      .............::::oooooooooo::...........
:::oooooooooo::oooOOOOOOOOOoo::........  ......::...::oo&&&&&&OOO::..     ....:::      ...  ...........:::ooooooooo::......   .....
:::oooOOooooo::::ooOOOOOOOOOOoo::......:::...:::...::...ooOO&&&&&&OOOoo::..    ....::::..   ...  ...........:::::ooooooo:::......  ......
::oooooo::::...::OOOOOOOOOOOoo::......:::::........ooOO&&&&OOOOOoo::..     .....::.....   ..........::::::oooooo:::.....   .......
 ESC

At this point in the command line i would compile and then:

```
./a.out < encoded_picture.txt > decoded_picture.txt
```

And then to compare to see if it work:

```
 diff decoded_picture.txt ascii_cat.txt
```

At this point i know that if `diff` displays an output, I've done it wrong.

Any help would be appreciated (actual program part3_file.c).

```
int length;
int i;
// loop until the end of input sentinel is seen
while (1)
{
    // get the first element in the line
    scanf("%d%c", &length, &character);
    if(length == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        // is it the sentinel? if so, then break out of the loop
        // reconstruct a line, as per part 2
        while ( length != -1 )
        {
            for( i = 0; i<= length; i++)
            {
                printf("%c", character);
            }
            scanf("%d%c", &length, &character);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: You have the line `scanf("%d%c", &length, &character);` so the file is not just ASCII text, it has some kind of structure. So please post a small sample input file, the required output file, and the faulty output file.

Comment: I have added the files I am working with, as well as what they look like.

Comment: @WeatherVane oops forgot to mention in previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question and you want to read `encoded_picture.txt` from `stdin` and then based on each encoded pair `'lc'` (that's `l` as in `length` and `c` as in `character`) output `l` number of characters `c` to `stdout` until length is `-1` where a `'\n'` is output, then you are on the right track. However your loop logic is a bit strange.

You can use your `scanf` format string `"%d%c"`. However, you always, always want to check the return of `scanf` to validate the expected number of conversions took place. For example, to read each pair until end of file is encountered you can do something like the following:

```
    while (scanf ("%d%c", &l, &c) == 2) {
```

Your next task, to repeatedly output the specified number of characters, you can simply do:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            printf ("%c", c);
```

(if `l == -1` the loop will not execute anyway, also ***note:*** the loop is `i < l` for `l` characters, where `i <= l` would result in `l+1` chars)

Your final task is to control the output of the newline in the event `l == -1`,

```
        if (l == -1)
            putchar ('\n');
```

Putting it together, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int l;
    char c;

    while (scanf ("%d%c", &l, &c) == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            printf ("%c", c);
        if (l == -1)
            putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Based on the `encoded_picture.txt` text you provided, that would result in something like the following (that looks like the start of Ratchet's ears):

```
$ ./bin/decodpic <dat/encpic.txt
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::. ....::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::. ....   ..:.     .:.::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::..:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::. ...   ....       .::::::..:
::::::::::::.::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::......  ..         .::::::..:
::::::::::::..:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::. ... ...           .::::::::
::::::::::::   .:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::..  . ..            .::::::::
::::::::::::.   .:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::. . ....             .::::::::
::::::::::::.     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::........               ::::::::
:::::::::::::. ..  .:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.......     ..         ::::::::
::::::::::::::  ..  .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::......      ...  .     ::::::::
::::::::::::::.  ..   .:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::......        ... ..    ::::::::
:::::::::::::::. ...   .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.....       .. ......  .::::::::
:::::::::::::::: ....    .:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.....     ...... .....  .::::::::
::::::::::::::::......     .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::......   ........ .....  .::::::::
:::::::::::::::::......     ..:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::......   ......... .....  .::::::::
:::::::::::::::::.......      ..::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::......     ........ .....  .::::::::
::::::::::::::::::.......       .::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::......     .......:. ... .  .::::::::
```

Look things over and let me know if I misunderstood or if you have questions.

---

**Writing Output WITHOUT a final POSIX line-end**

While this is improper, the `decoded_picture.txt` does not contain a POSIX line-end. If you run the first version of my code, and then use `diff -uNb decoded_picture.txt the_output.txt` you find the only difference is my code properly includes a POSIX line-end (e.g. `'\n'`) after the final line written. You can *dupe* the code into not writing a POSIX line-end by setting a toggle to only write the newline if characters were previously written in that line. That effectively prevent a final `newline`. You can do that as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int l, flag = 1;
    char c;

    while (scanf ("%d%c", &l, &c) == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            printf ("%c", c);
        if (l == -1) {
            if (flag) {
                putchar ('\n');
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
        else
            flag = 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Result**

Then testing the code and output, you find the following:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o bin/decodpic2 decodpic2.c
$ ./bin/decodpic2 <dat/encoded_picture.txt > dat/decode2.txt
$ diff -uNb dat/decoded_picture.txt dat/decode2.txt
(no output, the files match :)
```

While there is educational use in forcing a final write without a POSIX line-end -- *do not do this is real life* `:)`

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the response. I looked what you said over and tried to implement the code you suggested into my program. What you have suggested worked better than the code I originally had, but when  I go to use the diff command, there is still output which is the following: [dsmoore@sleet lab03]$ diff decoded_picture.txt ascii_cat.txt
125d124
< 
[dsmoore@sleet lab03]$

Comment: Post the file for comparison and make sure I have the full input. I've tried comparing against what you put in your question, but the input I have does no generate the full example (even though it does correctly use each of the pairs you provided) Compare the first line of output with `29: 1. 1 4. 36: 1. 1 4. 3 2. 1: 1. 5 1. 1: 1. 8: -1?` (e.g. 29-`:`, `-`.`, etc. Do you have a [pastebin.com account](http://pastebin.com/)? You can post your files there as plain text You can tell the data you posted doesn't go with the picture (there are no Oo or 8 in your data.)

Comment: Ok I have posted my files on http://pastebin.com/u/devinthemoore/1/?guest=1

Comment: The only part I am totally confused about in your code is the part where the ' scanf ' statement is in the ' while ' loop. I am not totally sure why it is also ' == 2 ' either. An explanation on that would be greatly appreciated. Also, as far as the files are concerned, I pipe ' encoded_picture.txt ' into my program, which then spits out what it gets into ' decoded_picture.txt ', in which case I compare whats in 'decoded_picture.txt' to whats in 'ascii_cat.txt'. Using ' diff ', there should be no output but it still displays what I said two comments ago.

Comment: The return for `scanf` is the ***match count*** (that is the number of format specifiers, e.g. `%d` and `%c` successfully matched and converted). You always ***validate*** the return of `scanf` to insure you are not processing garbage (e.g. you actually read a real value). Failure to do so is simply coding malpractice. I run the code and I get a cat. If you run `diff -uNb dat/decoded_picture.txt.txt dat/decode1.txt` you get `\ No newline at end of file` (so the only difference in the file my code creates is it properly includes a POSIX line end where the file you posted does not. `:)`

Comment: Ok thanks so much for the explanation of the while loop with scanf and == 2.  So the whole reason my file decoded_picture.txt is different from the ascii_cat.txt is because it does not introduce a new line at the end of file?

Comment: Right - sneaky S.O.B..... It is a good exercise that really makes you focus on each character written. Give it a try and report back.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I'm learning all kinds of new things today. The new code you suggested works like a charm. So flag essentially tells the program to not write a new line at the end of the file (therefore no weird output when using diff)? I'm starting to piece together what you have suggested now. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, that's all it does. Wish I could have helped more, but I've been in trial in Shelby Co., Texas since Monday, not more spare time until it goes to the jury.